# How to undo git pull with error message

Tags: git

I just did a mistake and would really need to undo a git pull command. The mistake was that I wrote `git pull origin devbranch` in stead of `git pull origin master`. So i fetched the wrong branch into my master branch on my site. I am lucky that the merge didn't go through though.

I now get this message when I do `git status`:

```
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 10 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:

        modified:   sites/all/modules/mymodule/mymodule.module

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        cache/normal/www.mysite.com/
        sites/default/private/temp/somefile.csv

root@server:/srv/www/mysite/public_html#
```

I know `git pull` consist of `git fetch` + `git merge`, and in this cas the merge is not completed, only the fetch part.

How do I go back to the state before my disastrous "`git pull`". I have already used git reflog to see what reference the former pull command used and then I did git `reset --hard a0d3fe6` (where a0d3fe6 is the reference from the previous pull). This didn't change anything. I still get the same message after `git status`. What to do?

Comment: To terminate an in-progress merge without committing it, use `git merge --abort`.

Comment: Thanks torek, You saved my day. Upvote of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this happens again remember that in a merge, git only adds commits.  If the merge had completed, all the original commits are still there.  So you can recover the previous state of your branch with

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

to see the commits that HEAD was on, (which is the list 'HEAD@{1}' uses):

```
git reflog -32
```

and at any time view the commits you have with

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph -32 --branch --tags --remotes
```

also if you are going to do something complex like a rebase you can tag the starting commit with

```
git tag MyStartingCommit
```

and then if things are all fouled up just restart the current branch with:

```
git reset --hard MyStartingCommit
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick question... what about the tilde (~) character after HEAD?

Comment: The tilde character means the commit before HEAD.  But you bring up a good point. That if the merge was a fast-forward, merge, then multiple commits were added, so I have amended my answer to use the reflog (see 'git help reflog').

Comment: Great answer. Thank you again.